# My javascript doesn't work in an external src page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

Hello I am making a flash gallery website and my javascript works when I put it inside a `<script></script>` tag within my html but when I try to move it to an external .js file it stops from working.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en"  onLoad="flashy()">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Flash Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Flash stuff">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="siteText">
    <h1>Anon Curb</h1>
    </div>
        <div id="flashmovie">
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="swfs/2cats.swf">'+
                <param name="movie" value="swfs/2cats.swf">
            </object>
        </div>
        <!-- end #container -->
    <div id="buttoncon">
<button id="rand">Random</button>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="next">next</button>
            <button id="back">Back</button>

            <div id="title">2cats</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <!-- end #wrapper -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: verdana, arial, hevetica, sans-serif;
}

#siteText {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

#flashmovie {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: -1%;
    float: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#flashmovie object {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

button {
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
}

#buttons {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
}

#buttoncon {
    top: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
}

#back,
#next {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}

#next {
    float: right;
}

#title {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #600;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#rand {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    left: 48%;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: .5%;
    margin-top: .5%;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
   var links = [
             'swfs/CP.swf',
             'swfs/2cats.swf', /* there is no limit to the array length */
             'swfs/4ChanBrightside.swf',
             'swfs/4chancity.swf',
             'swfs/2spooky4u.swf',
             'swfs/4channer.swf',
             'swfs/5_mile_walk.swf' /* no trailing comma after final item */
            ];
        var displaytext = [
                    'CP',
                   '2cats',
                   'f4ChanBrightside',
                   '4chancity',
                   '2spooky4u',
                   '4channer',
                   '5_mile_walk' /* no trailing comma after final item */
                  ];
        var c = 0
        var flashmovie, test, temp;

        function init() {
            flashmovie = document.getElementById('flashmovie');
            document.getElementById('back').onclick = function () {
                if (c == 0) {
                    c = links.length;
                }
                c--
                displayFiles();
            }

            document.getElementById('next').onclick = function () {
                if (c == links.length - 1) {
                    c = -1;
                }
                c++;
                displayFiles();
            }

            document.getElementById('rand').onclick = function () {
                temp = c;
                while (c == temp) {
                    c = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
                }
                displayFiles();
            }
        }

        function displayFiles() {

            test = links[c].substring(links[c].lastIndexOf('.') + 1, links[c].length);
            document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = displaytext[c];

            flashmovie.innerHTML =
                '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + links[c] + '">' +
                '<param name="movie" value="' + links[c] + '">' +
                '<\/object>';
        }
        window.addEventListener ?
            window.addEventListener('load', init, false) :
            window.attachEvent('onload', init);
});
```

So to recap the code works I think I've just messed up the way it's triggered like the JQuery $(document).ready thing or maybe I shouldn't use that to begin with? I'm new to javascript so any suggestions you have will help

Comment: It looks like you are including your script before you include jQuery. Can you try moving script tag for your file to the bottom of the body?

Comment: You need to include the jquery library before including your javascript file.

Comment: ..... facepalm, I've been on that for like half an hour and I can't beleive I forgot that event though I'm kinda new I knew knew that JQuery had to go before externals thank you sir :D

Comment: sigh, the good ole days... haha! Happens to the best of us!

Comment: Question: should this be taken down? Its not constructive to anyone except OP. Not hating, just stating.

Comment: Well I guess it could be but it wouldn't hurt anything for it to stay up would it?